# Обновить некоторые поля одной таблицы значениями из другой таблицы по условию

Tags: mysql, sql

Задана две таблицы (mysql),

```
id, name, fixed_name 
и
id, name
```

id - записей у первой и второй таблицы одинаковые.

Требуется поле `name` второй таблицы, заменить значениями поля `name` первой таблицы, для которых условие `fixed_name='Y'` истина.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это сделать минимальным кол-вом запросов ?

Вероятно, надо сделать join, и заменить одно поле `name` на другое по условию.
Но как это сделать, не знаю.

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) -> "Multiple-table syntax" & последний пример.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32835500 вот что нашел, как по мне как раз нужное решение.